# longlist grouped data not showing correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, grouping, longlistselector

This has been driving me nuts - missing something simple i know - but dont want to waste any more time if possible. have a long list on my page with its data source set thus:

```C#
var result = (from s in App.ViewModel.AllSampleData
              join j in App.ViewModel.AllJobData
              on s.SampleJobID equals j.JobID
              select new { j.JobNumber, s.SampleNumber }).GroupBy(j => j.JobNumber).ToList();

this.lstSamples.ItemsSource = result;
```

the markup is as follows:

```XAML
<phone:LongListSelector
    x:Name="lstJobSamplesGrouped"
    IsGroupingEnabled="True"
    GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SampleTemplate}"
    LayoutMode="List"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" 
    Width="436" Tap="lstSamples_Tap"/>
```

and the templates thus:

```XAML
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupHeaderTemplate">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26"  Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SampleTemplate">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26"  Text="{Binding SampleNumber}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

the key displays fine, but the grouped items are not showing:

should show something like this -

A2000
  001
  002
  003
A2001
  001
  002

but I get just

A2000
A2001
A2002

perhaps someone could shed some light on this for me

many thanks :)